# ActiveRecord where.not is not working/ weird behavior

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

User `has_many` Plans. I'm trying to find the IDs of all Users that do NOT have a Plan with status of "canceled". Would love to know what's explaining the behavior below.

For context, what should be returned is this:

```
User.select { |u| u.plans.select { |p| p.status != "canceled" }.count > 0 }.map(&:id)
# => [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63]
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
# statement 1
User.joins(:plans).where.not("plans.status" => "canceled").map(&:id)
# User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "plans" ON "plans"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("plans"."status" != 'canceled')
# => [44]

# statement 2
User.joins(:plans).where("plans.status != ?", "canceled").map(&:id)
# User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "plans" ON "plans"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (plans.status != 'canceled')
# => [44]

# statement 3
User.joins(:plans).where("plans.status == ?", nil).map(&:id)
# User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "plans" ON "plans"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (plans.status == NULL)
# => []

# statement 4
User.joins(:plans).where("plans.status" => nil).map(&:id)
# User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "plans" ON "plans"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "plans"."status" IS NULL
# => [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 41, 44, 42, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 60, 62, 63]
```

Questions:

1. Why are statement 3 and 4 not returning the same result?
2. Why are statement 1 and 2 (fortunately these are the same and are returning the same result) not returning the same result as statement 4? For context, I'd rather not search on `nil`, but on `"canceled"`. And I can confirm that all plans have either a status of `nil` or `"canceled"`

**UPDATE PER REQUEST**

```
# plan with nil status
Plan.where(status: nil).first
# => <Plan id: 1, zipcode: "94282", selected_plan: 1, meal_type: "Chef's choice (mixed)", most_favorite: "", least_favorite: "", allergies: "", start_date: "2015-05-27 00:00:00", delivery_address: "d", delivery_instructions: "", phone1: "10", phone2: "222", phone3: "2222", agree_tos: true, user_id: 20, created_at: "2015-05-24 05:18:40", updated_at: "2015-06-21 04:54:31", stripe_subscription_id: nil, stripe_invoice_number: nil, cancel_reason: nil, cancel_reason_other: nil, nps: nil, nps_open: nil, cancel_open: nil, status: nil, referred_by_code: nil>

# plan with canceled status
Plan.where(status: "canceled").first
# => <Plan id: 20, zipcode: "12345", selected_plan: 5, meal_type: "Meat (with veggies)", most_favorite: "", least_favorite: "", allergies: "", start_date: "2015-06-08 00:00:00", delivery_address: "asdf", delivery_instructions: "", phone1: "333", phone2: "333", phone3: "3333", agree_tos: true, user_id: 38, created_at: "2015-06-01 21:39:54", updated_at: "2015-06-23 06:23:10", stripe_subscription_id: "sub_6OKkJoNx2u8ZXZ", stripe_invoice_number: 0, cancel_reason: nil, cancel_reason_other: "", nps: 6, nps_open: "", cancel_open: "", status: "canceled", referred_by_code: nil>
```

Comment: The correct syntax for SQL is one equal sign, not two

Comment: @LoganSerman that doesn't seem to matter, either one or two `=` return blank

Comment: For null you need to use IS NULL

Comment: Ah ok that's fair. But what I'd really like to do is to try to get statements 1 and 2 working. Thoughts there?

Comment: Can you post your dB contents one each having status `nil` and `cancelled` ?

Comment: @abhinavmsra ok just added!

Comment: To answer Q2, i need the query the server does. Can you post it?

Comment: What dB are you using?

Comment: PostGreSQL in production & SQLite in development

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Question 1:

You missed the concept that in conditional sql, the arguments that follow the condition are replaced in place of `?` not compared to. So, replace the double `==` with `=`.

```
User.joins(:plans).where("plans.status = ?", nil).map(&:id)
```

Comment: Ok (Sorry for the break, needed to run urgent errand), I added the queries as well above, on this question I really need either statement 1 or 2 to work, any ideas there? Your answer above will just get me a `[]` which isn't what I'm looking for either