# ActiveRecord query returns object twice (2 instances of same object)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Something is probably wrong with my query, not sure exactly what...

```
# this is the correct output
Plan.select { |p| p.plan_dates.select { |pd| pd.ddate.to_date >= cancel_from_this_date }.count > 0 }.map(&:id)
# => [54]

# this is the output where the object is returned twice
Plan.joins(:plan_dates).where("plan_dates.ddate >= ?", cancel_from_this_date.in_time_zone).pluck("id")
# => [54, 54]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite natural.

`Plan.joins(:plan_dates)` returns `a Plan object for all Plan with PlanDate`.

Now, if multiple `plan_dates` have single `Plan`, you will get duplicate `plans`.

To resolve this, you need to use `uniq` as follows:

`Plan.joins(:plan_dates).uniq.where("plan_dates.ddate >= ?", cancel_from_this_date.in_time_zone).pluck("id")`

Comment: your welcome. you can study more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: ugh i read that whole thing but i still am running into a zillion problems

Comment: can you mention them, if i can help?

Comment: YES good lord yes: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658941/activerecord-not-returning-when-searching-on-parents-children, 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644628/activerecord-where-not-is-not-working-weird-behavior

Comment: So, a Model-based query, filtered through another table's values with join, can return duplicates of the instances passed as the set to be filtered (the intention being to 'reduce' the set by returning only the matching values from the original-set).  Absolutely crazy unexpected result from a step which should be subtractive - and quite difficult to track down.  Thank you!!!