# ActiveRecord not returning when searching on parent's children

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Would love to know what simple error it is that I'm making this time...

```
current_user = User.find(60)
Plan.joins(:user).where("users.id" => current_user.id).where("plans.status" => nil)
# Plan Load (8.6ms)  SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "plans"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = 60 AND "plans"."status" IS NULL
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Plan id: 54....]

current_user.plans.where("status == ?",nil)
# Plan Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans"  WHERE "plans"."user_id" = ? AND (status == NULL)  [["user_id", 60]]
# => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

Not understanding why the second statement isn't finding the plan..

Comment: Do you have a status column in `users` table too?

Comment: nope that was my first thought, but status is unique to plans

Comment: In SQL, checking for NULL is done with either `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, so you would do `current_user.plans.where('status IS NULL')`.  Or better yet, `current_user.plans.where(status: nil)` or `current_user.plans.where(plans: { status: nil})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the concept that in conditional sql, the arguments that follow the condition are replaced in place of `?` not compared to. So, replace the double `==` with `=`.

```
current_user.plans.where("status = ?",nil)
```

or simply,

```
current_user.plans.where(status: nil)
```

Comment: can you post the query? I see nothing wrong with my ORM.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but I'm curious, why is it that doing this `current_user.plans.where(status: nil)` returns the Plan, but doing this: `current_user.plans.where.not(status: "canceled")` does NOT? Plans have status that's either nil or canceled

Comment: @james, read up on three-valued logic.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic